# Android SDK, second activty java/xml causing app to crash

Tags: java, android, xml, sdk

I have an app with several activities in it. And had to change some of the flow within the pages. To do this I created a flyout side menu. The flyout menu works on its own . But when added to the main app it causes the whole app to crash.

So I will be on the main screen and click to go to the activity that has the flyout in it. And the app crashes between the 2 activities. Get and error say that there is something wrong with the onCreate().

```
    this.root = (FlyOutContainer)         this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
```

Just to help give a little more info. I am creating an app with a flyout menu that should allow me to click on various buttons and go to new activities. But I can not even get to the activiity that has the menu in it. And not sure how to switch between various activities.

Comment: Please post the full exception shown in your logcat.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.flyoutcontaine.FlyOutContainer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.wkpescherine.celebpage-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
 
                                                                                        at com.example.wkpescherine.celebpage.Home.onCreate(Home.java:16)